# Destructive cropping of text outside of view in PDF(after crop by BRISS) for conversion to epub

Tags: pdf, accessibility, ebook, epub, pdfedit

I have vision issues and read eBooks with TTS. But a lot of eBooks are only available in PDF format and PDFs are awful when you convert them to ePub because of headers and footers.

Then I found a FOSS software called BRISS which crops PDFs to remove headers and footers and also has advanced extraction features. I was overjoyed. But after converting the PDF to ePub, I realized that BRISS only hides the data outside of crop, it doesn't remove it.
And when the cropped PDF is converted to ePub, the headers and footers that were invisible in the PDF will be visible in the ePub.

Is there a software that is able to destroy all text outside of view in a PDF instead of just hiding it? And I don't want to fiddle with Regexes in Calibre.

I guess if there is a software that does destructive crop then I can set the crop(of the BRISS cropped file) to a small amount so that everything outside of view is destroyed

Comment: Questions specifically asking for software products are "shopping recommendation" questions, and are off topic on this site. You may be able to rephrase this question to focus on the problem you are trying to solve without explicitly asking for a software recommendation. I recommend that you do that. Also, reading the Help section may be a good idea to learn about the rules of this place and why they exist.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a good question, but belongs on Software Recommendations SE.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, though this a paid one. Still hoping for a free solution.

First use BRISS to crop.

The next steps involve using Adobe Acrobat Pro.

1. In Acrobat Pro go to tools. Add `Redact` under `Protect and Standardize`.
2. The open the BRISS cropped PDF and then click Redact button on the RHS of the software. It only appears if you have added `Redact` from Tools.
3. Then click `Santize Document` and click `OK`. This removes all hidden data.

TL;DR: First use BRISS to crop and then use `Santizie document` from `Redact` in Tools in Adobe Acrobat Pro. This removes all hidden content(hidden by BRISS).

Then convert the eBook to ePub.